# How can i resolve token in general?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

Can you help me please?
I have a parameter

`env_name = CfnParameter(self, "EnvName", type="String", description="Name of environment", default="")`

and code

```
my_env_name = env_name.value.to_string()+""
self.vpc = ec2.Vpc(self, "VPC",
           vpc_name=my_env_name+"-vpc",
           subnet_configuration=[ec2.SubnetConfiguration(
               subnet_type=ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC,
               name=my_env_name+"-public",
               cidr_mask=21
           )
```

When i do  `vpc_name=my_env_name+"-vpc"` - all good, VPC is creating with required name.

When i try to do `name=my_env_name+"-public"` i have error message  `ID components may not include unresolved tokens: ${Token[EnvName.Ref.212]}-publicSubnet1`.

When i try to do
`name=Token.as_string(Fn.ref("EnvName"))` - error message
`Resolution error: ID components may not include unresolved tokens: ${Token[TOKEN.218]}Subnet1.`

How can i resolve token  in general?

Comment: You can't resolve tokens. They're resolved automatically during deployment, and you cannot include them in physical names. `vpc_name` is not the physical name of the VPC (just a tag), so it's allowed there.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Can i use value from cfnParameter as a string inside of my stack? for example i want to add second part to env_name?

Comment: Sure, as long as it's not part of a physical ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on @gshpychka's comment, tokens represent values that are not known at synthesis time. You can read more about them here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/tokens.html

Tokens cannot be resolved during synthesis, so in your case `vpc_name=my_env_name+"-vpc"` works because the CDK will turn that into a Cfn intrinsic functions that will resolve the value during the deployment of the stack.